# Flatpickr: cant clear the input when adding enableTime option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flatpickr

I'm using flatpickr in React, and I'm having an issue after adding `enableTime` option, which is when clearing the input it automatically resets the input's date value.

Here's my code
[stackblitz DatePicker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y1nfj6)

Comment: Hi Ali, any luck fixing this issue? Or did you report it as bug with FlatPickr? I ran into the same thing just now: if I remove a date by pressing Delete and click outside, the field gets cleared (as expected) but if `enableTime` is on then it cancels the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you see Flatpickr source code then you can find for clearing :

After opening dialog select input then, press keyboard `Delete` button then press keyboard `Esc` key

or you can add a little icon inside or outside input for clearing input by setting value property to null/undefined

Comment: I've done that already, but that's not the problem. when the input is empty and therefore the user clicks to pick a date and then loses focus (clicks outside the datepicker's box) hence he did not pick any date. So, flatpickr will automatically add an unwanted date